# ajax not working on chrome (that worked in firefox) possibly due to event error

Tags: jquery, ajax, google-chrome, cross-browser

my script is not working on chrome but working perfectly on firefox

script is as follows and r_tour is the id of the select element and option is an option

```
$("#r_tour option").click(function(){
     var value = $(this).val(); $.post(      
        'url',
        {"id": value}, function(data){
        $(div).html(data);}, "html" ); 
})
```

and the link is [here](http://www.websmartint.com/demo/reservation/inquiry/tour/10). on this link you will get the default value loaded from ajax (since ajax is called on document load) but (ajax requested event event will not load).

I think its possibly due to event but still don't have a clue.

**UPDATE::**

this piece of code is also not working on my localserver

```
$(function (){
$("#r_tour option").click(function(){
     var value = $(this).val(); 
     alert(value);
})
});
```

Comment: Have you thought about using the change event on the select element rather than click on the options? I can believe there might be issues with clicking on options since they don't really have any existence of their own, they are just data for the select and it is possible therefore that chrome (rightly or wrongly) is dealing with them like this. I should note that the change event potentially has slightly different behaviour too (in that the event wont' fire when clicking on the currently selected item).

Comment: Yup!! Chris you are right so is Duchie432!!

Comment: Good Answer. Not sure who got there first, so +1!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you verify whether or not this works for you? It should accomplish the same thing.

```
$("#r_tour option").click(function(){
     var value = $(this).val(); 
     $(div).load (url, 'id=' + uriEncodeComponent(value));
})
```

**UPDATE**

I see now. It seems like `#r_tour` is a select box, so why not just trigger this code when the value of the select box changes? Use `$("#r_tour").change()` instead of `$("#r_tour option").click()`

See http://jsfiddle.net/L5Ktr/1/

```
$("#r_tour").change(function(){
     var value = $(this).val(); 
     $(div).load (url, 'id=' + uriEncodeComponent(value));
})
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
$("#r_tour option").live("click", function(){
     var value = $(this).val(); 
     $(div).load(url, { id: value});
});
```

And this code ?:

```
$("#r_tour").live("click", function(){
     var value = $(this).val(); 
     alert(value);
});
```

Comment: thats now working either. i mean for the chrome you code works fine on firefox. are you sure that works on chrome